# Where to find TortoiseSvn Subwcrev Error code list?

Tags: tortoisesvn

Today one of our devs had "error 9009" from my subwcrev post-build command. It worked fine in the command line. What fixed it was restarting Visual Studio. A couple of other people found that updating SVN and/or ensuring it's on the path were the culprits;
http://forum.battleclinic.com/index.php?topic=42617.0;Building-problems
http://www.autismcollaborative.org/wiki/index.php?title=Troubleshooting

I was surprised not to see a list of SubWcRev's error code's and their meanings. Does anyone know where to find that? thank you!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can find the error codes in the [source](http://code.google.com/p/tortoisesvn/source/browse/trunk/src/SubWCRev/SubWCRev.cpp#140).

```
// Internal error codes
#define ERR_SYNTAX      1   // Syntax error
#define ERR_FNF         2   // File/folder not found
#define ERR_OPEN        3   // File open error
#define ERR_ALLOC       4   // Memory allocation error
#define ERR_READ        5   // File read/write/size error
#define ERR_SVN_ERR     6   // SVN error
// Documented error codes
#define ERR_SVN_MODS    7   // Local mods found (-n)
#define ERR_SVN_MIXED   8   // Mixed rev WC found (-m)
#define ERR_OUT_EXISTS  9   // Output file already exists (-d)
#define ERR_NOWC       10   // the path is not a working copy or part of one
```

Comment: Thank you Stefan! I'm sorry I didn't click accept earlier. I had some login issues.

Answer (score -2):

Remove it from:  Project--> Properties ---> Build Event --> Pre build event command line

subwcrev "$(SolutionDir)." "$(ProjectDir)Properties\AssemblyInfoTemplate.cs" "$(ProjectDir)Properties\AssemblyInfo.cs" -f

Then build the project

Comment: The question states a post build event. Also, there is no indication that the poster is using subwcrev to substitute svn values into the assembly info. Finally, bluntly removing the command is hardly a solution, at best a work-around.