# Exit Code 216 with SubWCRev

Tags: visual-studio, svn, tortoisesvn, pre-build-event

I'm using SubWCRev to automatically update the version info of a project. When another programmer pulls this project all the pre-build hooks fail with an exit code of 216. The only thing we use in the pre-build hook is SubWCRev.

[This is the only exit code documentation I can find](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10401275/where-to-find-tortoisesvn-subwcrev-error-code-list) besides the [source code](https://code.google.com/p/tortoisesvn/source/browse/trunk/src/SubWCRev/SubWCRev.cpp#140) which does not have this specific exit code documented.

I am just curious as to what exit code 216 actually means?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe it's this:
ERROR_EXE_MACHINE_TYPE_MISMATCH
216 (0xD8)
This version of %1 is not compatible with the version of Windows you're running. Check your computer's system information and then contact the software publisher.

So... maybe it's a 64-bit binary on win32?  Or something like that?

Comment: 32 vs 64 bit problem. Good call.